# How to get specific words from Word document（*.doc） using C#?

Tags: c#, regex, ms-word

I want to get the specific content from curriculum vitae,like name and age. How to do it with C#. Regular expressions perhaps？

Comment: http://docx.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is using **string.Split** without argument(splits by white-space characters):

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] words = line.Split();
        foreach(string word in words)
        {
            foreach(Char c in word)
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know, if you have any questions.

Comment: OK,thank you very mush!

Comment: If the answer helped you, I would appreciate if you could accept it. Thanks.